# Django Webpack compiling misc JS in brand new Django/ReactJS app to make 21,500 line file

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack

I have been following the below tutorial to get Django and ReactJS working:

http://geezhawk.github.io/using-react-with-django-rest-framework

I started a brand new Django project, added an app called `home`, but have otherwise done nothing else except what is outlined in the tutorial.

Anyway, when I compile the JS it creates a file that is about 21,500 lines and 800kb. My ReactJS file is only about 20 lines and there is no other JS to speak of from the Django app. It seems like it is compiling dependencies in the `virtualenv` or something. Anyway to prevent this?

**webpack.config.js**

```
//require our dependencies
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = {
    //the base directory (absolute path) for resolving the entry option
    context: __dirname,
    //the entry point we created earlier. Note that './' means 
    //your current directory. You don't have to specify the extension  now,
    //because you will specify extensions later in the `resolve` section
    entry: './assets/js/index', 

    output: {
        //where you want your compiled bundle to be stored
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'), 
        //naming convention webpack should use for your files
        filename: '[name]-[hash].js', 
    },

    plugins: [
        //tells webpack where to store data about your bundles.
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}), 
        //makes jQuery available in every module
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery' 
        })
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            //a regexp that tells webpack use the following loaders on all 
            //.js and .jsx files
            {test: /\.jsx?$/, 
                //we definitely don't want babel to transpile all the files in 
                //node_modules. That would take a long time.
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                //use the babel loader 
                loader: 'babel-loader', 
                query: {
                    //specify that we will be dealing with React code
                    presets: ['react'] 
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        //tells webpack where to look for modules
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        //extensions that should be used to resolve modules
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'] 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A couple of things

1. **React and jQuery are part of your bundle.** Yes you only wrote ~20 lines of code, but you are also importing React into your project, and since you only have one entry defined, everything you import will get bundled into a single bundle (which may be fine for your needs). What's more, your Webpack config also imports jQuery globally. You can break dependencies up into their own bundle or into multiple bundles and load them on demand if needed.
2. **You are bundling the development version of React.** When Webpack runs and bundles your project it will do different things based on whether `process.env` evaluates to "development" or "production". The idea being to make development easier and build times faster during development. In the case of React, you are getting its development version with lots of comments and extra checks (more kilobytes) simply because your environment isn't set to "production".
3. **Tree shaking, deduping, and minification are your friends.** I'll let you look into these, but basically, tree shaking (part of Webpack 2) makes it so you only bundle the part of a library you actually use. In webpack 1.x, there's a deduping plugin that will remove duplicate sections of code, and minification will, well, minify your code. You can setup your Webpack config to run these steps only when being run in a production build environment.

Try swapping your plugins section out with this to start:

```
plugins: [
    ...(process.env === 'production' ? [
        // set webpack process env to production
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production') },
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),  // webpack 1.x only
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ comments: false }),
    ] : []),
    //tells webpack where to store data about your bundles.
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}), 
    //makes jQuery available in every module
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery' 
    }),
],
```